# Evaluating an Expression in PHP That Has ==0 Inside

Tags: php

I have code like this:

```
$thi = $dinfoarray->totalItems;
        var_dump($thi);
        // $thi is NULL
    if ($thi == 0) {
       // execute code here if $thi = 0.
    else {
        print "We have issues. The query is: $queryl";
        die();
    }
```

the if part is meant to execute when $thi is integer 0. But when var_dump shows that $thi = NULL, the if part still executes. Why, and how do I make it work?

Comment: The null must be being coerced into 0. Does PHP have `===`? I remember another language besides JS does.

Comment: Yes, PHP has `===`.